Efficient computation of factorial in finite field
What is the state of the art for fast computation of the factorial function $n!$ and more generally of $\prod_{1\leq x\leq n} (x-q)$ (rising/falling factorial) in a finite field?
I found just one paper on "An efficient approach to calculate factorials in prime field"
https://subakti.com/wp-content/uploads/2021-10-13-An-Efficient-Approach-to-Calculate-Factorials-in-Prime-Field.pdf
I would have expected there to be much more.  I welcome references.  Thank you.
